# Accessing main class instance methods from another class instantiated within the main class

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have two classes: "Game" class and "Unit" class.

Game is instantiated just after the program starts in the Main function.
Inside Game class constructor I created some "Unit" class instances.

Then I want one of my Units to run a method from the Game class instance I created in Main function (for example to use Game's built in random number engine)

Is that possible? What is the best way of accessing parent's instance method from the class instantiated within this class.

As I couldn't really get how to do it properly I decided to use "static" method, although my first needs was to use an instance of a Class. Still couldn't get it to work..
This is my tryout of use random from my Game class (but not an instance of that class as I wanted), I was able to only run a static print function but static random just throws an error: LNK2001  unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::random_device Game::rgen" (?rgen@Game@@2Vrandom_device@std@@A)

By the way mt19937 is giving similar error. Using Visual Studio 2015.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Game;
class Unit;

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    static void printSomething(); // test function

    static std::random_device rgen; // main game random generator

    // a shorthand function for quick generating random numbers 
    static int rnd(int min, int max){
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uid(min, max);
        return uid(rgen);
    }
    static double rnd(double min, double max){
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urd(min, max);
        return urd(rgen);
    }
};

class Unit
{
public:
    Unit() {
        std::cout << "unit created\n";
        Game::printSomething(); // this works
        std::cout << "random num is " << Game::rnd(1,100) << "!\n"; // this doesn't work
    }
};

// ********************************************** //
int main()
{
    Game game; // main game instance
}

// ********************************************** //

Game::Game() {
    Unit * unit = new Unit;
}

void Game:: printSomething() {
    std::cout << "Printing something!\n";
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty subjective question. My choice would be to choose a different class design, with the random functions encapsulated in a `Random` object that you pass to the `Unit`.

Comment: Why not pass the generator around, it seems as if it deserves its own class

Answer (score 2):

You get that error since

```
static std::random_device rgen;
```

isn't declared outside class.

You should add the following line after the class definition:

```
std::random_device Game::rgen (*any constructor arguments needed*);
```

The reason that print works is, because it doesn't use the non-declared static variable rgen.

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't answer main question, what is the way to access main class instance methods from another class instantiated within the main class?

Comment: @Shabrido For that, you should've done some google research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405069/inner-class-accessing-outer-class

Comment: Hey.. thanks for this link, it's pretty much what I was looking for, trust me, I did some research but probably using wrong keywords.